# How to find the cdf

Tags: probability-theory

A number U is chosen at random in the interval [0, 1].

(b) S = U(1 − U) < 1/4.

13 Find the cumulative distribution function F and the density function f for
the random variables S. 
Attempt: I tried to use the theorem P (Y is less than or equal to y). Then I got P(U (1-U) is less than or equal to y) then I got P (u-u^2 is less than or equal to y). Then, I factored out a u to get 
P(u is less than to equal to y/(1-u)). I tried to isolate E the U, but I was unable to get U by itself. How should isolate the U to find the cdf for this problem?

Comment: $$u(1-u)>y\iff u^2-u+\frac14<\frac14-y\iff \frac12-\sqrt{\frac14-y}<u<\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14-y}$$

Comment: I was curious how you got the (1/4) on both sides?

Comment: And thank u for ur help!